# Spring - Context initialization failed

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am getting an error when I am trying to run my spring app.

ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed "spring"

**Stack trace:**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09:56:47.047 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failedg
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.findDescriptor(ReactiveWrappers.java:281) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isNoValueType(ReactiveWrappers.java:186) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isWrapper(ReactiveWrappers.java:268) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.supports(ReactiveWrappers.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:591) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:461) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.usesReactiveType(ReactiveWrappers.java:173) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.isReactiveRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:129) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:145) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41010) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4661) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45009) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45012) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    ... 69 more
fev 21, 2019 9:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exceção ao enviar evento de contexto iniciado para instância listener da classe [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.findDescriptor(ReactiveWrappers.java:281)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isNoValueType(ReactiveWrappers.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isWrapper(ReactiveWrappers.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.supports(ReactiveWrappers.java:158)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:591)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:461)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.usesReactiveType(ReactiveWrappers.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.isReactiveRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:380)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:85)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4661)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173)
    ... 69 more

fev 21, 2019 9:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
fev 21, 2019 9:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/producao] startup failed due to previous errors
fev 21, 2019 9:56:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/produtoDB" auth="Container"
        factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
        type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        driverClass="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/produto?useSSL=false"
        user="root"
        password="root"
        initialPoolSize="5"
        minPoolSize="5"
        maxPoolSize="5"
    />
</Context>
```

**JPAConfiguration.java**

```
package com.ablogic.produto.config;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.ablogic.produto.model.Carro;

import com.ablogic.produto.repository.Carro;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Carro.class)

public class JPAConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {

            JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true); 
            return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/produtoDB"); 
        }

        @Bean 
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
            adapter.setShowSql(true); 
            adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);  adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            return adapter;

        }

        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
            factory.setPackagesToScan(Carro.class.getPackage().getName()); 
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
            return transactionManager;

        }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ablogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>produto</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <flyway-maven-plugin.version>5.2.4</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>8.0.15</mysql-connector-java.version>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>

    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

    <!-- Bean Validation / Hibernate Validator -->
    <hibernate-validator.version>6.0.14.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

    <!-- Thymneleaf - Layout Dialect -->
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>

    <!-- Loggin -->
    <log4j.version>2.11.2</log4j.version>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.25</jcl-over-slf4j.version>

    <!-- JPA / Hibernate -->
    <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <spring-data-jpa.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version> <!-- 1.10.2.RELEASE -->

  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation / Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf - Layout Dialect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA/ Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate - Java 8 support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**CarrosController.java**

```
package com.ablogic.produto.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.ablogic.produto.model.Carro;
import com.ablogic.produto.repository.Carros;

@Controller
public class CarrosController {

    @Autowired
    private Carros carros;

    @RequestMapping("/carros/novo")
    public String novo(Carro carro) {
        cervejas.findAll();
        return "carro/CadastroCarro";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/carro/novo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String cadastrar(@Valid Carro carro, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return novo(carro);
        }


        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Carro salvo com sucesso !");

        return "redirect:/carros/novo";
    }

}
```

**Package Explorer**

[image]

I'm using MySQL v.8.0 and Tomcat v.9.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like&you have definitely a (spring) "version clash": spring-data (2.1.5) depends on spring `5.1.5.RELEASE` ... [see spring-data-parent/pom.xml](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-parent-2.1.5.RELEASE.pom)

Comment: ...possible solutions: 1. use spring 5.1.5 (import spring-data-parent/pom). 2. downgrade spring-data to...the version, which depends "closest"(<=)  on spring-4.3.1...

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you for your reply. I change the JPA's version to 5.1.5.Final and same error occurs. I'll try the other solution.

Comment: pardon, *not* hibernate version, **spring** version, please! (hibernate version ...might be different thread/case/issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the provided

- pom details:

  ```
  <spring-framework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
  <spring-data-jpa.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
  ```
- and error message:

  > java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: **org/springframework/core**/ReactiveTypeDescriptor **at org.springframework.data**.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.findDescriptor(ReactiveWrappers.java:281)

, the issue is clear:

`spring-data:2.1.5.RELEASE` [depends](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-parent-2.1.5.RELEASE.pom) on `spring:5.1.5.RELEASE` and (at runtime) relies on (the existence of) `org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor`, which was just "not in place" in `spring:4.3.1.RELEASE` ([introduced in spring 5.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapter.html)), which is the version you declare as direct dependency (and overwrite any potential transient (higher) versions).

Possible solutions (ordered by my preference):

1. (If applicable) Upgrade Spring to `5.1.5.RELEASE` (latest). Many possible approaches here, "quickest" in your case:

   `<spring-framework.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>`
2. If you are free to upgrade Spring, but only regarding "minor version" (so to latest 4, but not to 5), then use:

   - `spring-data:1.9.9.RELEASE`
   - and `spring:4.3.13.RELEASE` ([see here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.9.RELEASE/spring-data-parent-1.9.9.RELEASE.pom))
3. If you are bound to your (exact) Spring version, you can downgrade spring-data:

   - to `1.8.9.RELEASE` - it [depends](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.8.9.RELEASE/spring-data-parent-1.8.9.RELEASE.pom) on `spring:4.2.9.RELEASE` (the closest <= `4.3.1.RELEASE`)
   - to `1.9.0.RELEASE` - it [depends](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/1.9.0.RELEASE/spring-data-parent-1.9.0.RELEASE.pom) on `spring:4.3.6.RELEASE` (the closest >= `4.3.1.RELEASE`)

   ... which could work without further issues.

---

In any case this maven command can shed some light (exemplary with `spring-core` artifactId) and is very useful in case of dependency conflicts:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-core
```

Comment: Perfect ! It works... I upgraded Spring to 5.1.5.RELEASE. Thank you so much.